# Reset rain drop LEDs after it reaches a certain point

Tags: power-supply, voltage, power, current, resistors

[image]

Referring to [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SHyNOOJSe98&ab_channel=SDevElectronics), this CD4017 is connected to 10 LEDs to produce a rain effect. May I know how to reset the entire circuit after, for example, 23 times of rain drop effect (each LED has lit up)?

For clarification, this 23 times is referring to LED light up from start to end and then from start to end again and then from start to third LED, now this combines to 20 times (2 loops) + 3 times?

Comment: Then what would happen?  The 3rd LED stays on permanently, or they all turn off until the power is recycled?

Comment: @HandyHowie, they will all be off, and after you manually push a  reset button , the cycle continues again which is  led light up from start to end and then from start to end again and then from start to third led :). Do u think this can be solved using a counter :) or any easy method?

Comment: I'm guessing that the CD4017 is clocked with that 8-pin astable oscillator chip - a 555? You might concentrate on finding a way to stop this chip from continuing its counting cycle. To do that, you'd want to understand how it works. A 4017 chip has a "reset" pin. Look at CD4017 data sheet to discover how the reset logic functions.